# django save_model() error creating a new object with m2m fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model `models.py`:

```
class MyModelClass(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    m2m_1 = models.ManyToManyField(A, blank=True, null=True)     
    m2m_2 = models.ManyToManyField(B, blank=True, null=True) 
    fk    = models.ForeignKey('C')
    int   = models.IntegerField()
```

and an `admin.py` class:

```
class MyModelClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)

    #Get all fields selected in MyModelClass m2m_2
    def get_selected_in_m2m_2(self, obj):
        sel = obj.m2m_2.all() #This line is the one for i get an error. The error is described below.
        return sel

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """When creating a new object, set the creator field.
        """
        m2m_2_selected = self.get_selected_in_m2m_2(obj)
        print m2m_2_selected

        print request.user
        if not change:
            obj.creator = request.user
        obj.save()
```

The problem:
Everything works if i click "Save" button on already **existing** MyModelClass's object in my admin-page.
But if i try to **create** a new model object in admin-page and click the "Save" button(to save  a new object, not to update existing one), i'll get an error:`'MyModelClass' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.`


Sorry for my English. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    """When creating a new object, set the creator field.
    """
    if not change:
        obj.creator = request.user

    super(MyModelClassAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    m2m_2_selected = self.get_selected_in_m2m_2(obj)
    print m2m_2_selected
    print request.user
```

Answer (score 1):

Very common problem. You haven't got object, so you can't set m2m relationship. Try to use super function (I'm sorry, can't remember proper usage of it, but you'll easly find it in docs) to create this object (well, process pure function before chages) and then modify it and save.

Comment: Upvoted as you were the first to say to use super() function, save and the edit. Thanks